# Finding selected value in a select box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a quiz application involving a select box. The user selects an option and when they press a button, it should check if the selected option is the correct answer by checking an array of values. I can't figure out how to get the selected value from the select box. I've tried to find information about this, but I only want to use JS, no JQuery. I tried using:

```
var item = document.getElementById("selections");
var selection = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;
```

but I get a `Type Error`, saying that `item.selectedIndex` isn't defined. I'm confused because from what I found, `selectedIndex` is a default property of select tags? I've only worked with radio buttons before, using a for loop and checking every option to see which was checked, but I can't use that here. I don't know if it matters, but I'm doing this without a form tag, just linking a js function to an event listener on a button. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here is a fiddle of my code as per request: https://jsfiddle.net/jmf68ycu/

The part where the problem lies is in the `submit()` function in the first line.

Update: I found something online about the problem having to do with JS trying to call the element before the element is loaded, so I put the variables inside the function, which is only called when the button is pressed. The problem still persists (same error).

Comment: What is your `id="selections"`? Can you reproduce your problem in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I've added a fiddle of my code. I've also checked to make sure that it isn't a syntax error. I initially had the line `var form = document.getElementsByName("capitals");` but then changed it to `id` and added an `id` property to the `select` tag. Now, however, it says that `form` is null.

Comment: I noticed that when I try and use `var form = document.getElementById("capitals");`, the console tells me that `Type Error: form is null`, but when I try `var form = document.getElementsByName("capitals");`, I get `Type Error: form.selectedIndex is undefined.` when I give the `select` tag the same id and name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use like this

```
var item = document.getElementById("selections").value;
```

you select value store item variable

this code use full for you. :)

Comment: Hmmm I don't get the error now, but it displays the value as `undefined`... Any idea why its having trouble assigning the actual value of the option? I don't get any more errors, but when the variable that I am assigning the value to just sets to "undefined"... Regardless, I think you answered my original problem, which deserves an accepted answer (:

Comment: i saw jsfiddle . you select box not give id name is 'selections' .please add id .its work fine

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error somewhere. your code looks right. you probably aren't getting the right id. your first line probably doesn't return the right select.

```js
var e = document.getElementById("bla");
var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert(str);
```

```html
<select id="bla">
  <option value="val1">test1</option>
  <option value="val2" selected="selected">test2</option>
  <option value="val3">test3</option>
</select>
```